# Computer Reboots After "sti" Instruction

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

I am trying to implement interrupts in x86 operating system project. However, after loading interrupt descriptor table with lidt, I issue sti command and this "sti" command reboots the computer. And also, I am in the protected mode. Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things cause exceptions. When the CPU can't start the corresponding exception handler it falls back to a generic "double fault" exception, and when the CPU can't start that exception handler the CPU falls back to a "triple fault" condition which mostly means that the computer is reset.

It's likely that there are pending IRQs (that occurred while interrupts were masked with "`cli`" and have been waiting for CPU to be ready to receive them); so when you do "`sti`" the interrupt controller sees the CPU is ready to receive an IRQ now and immediately sends one to the CPU; and likely that the interrupt handler for whichever IRQ the CPU receives is causing an exception (that leads to double fault, that leads to triple fault/reset).

The easiest way to figure out what is happening is to run it under an emulator that tells you what happened in its logs. The alternative is to write usable exception handler/s for any exceptions that are involved (most likely, a general protection fault exception handler); so that the exception handler can give you information about what went wrong (e.g. the "error code" provided by the CPU to the general protection fault handler may indicate which IDT entry the CPU tried to use for the IRQ).

Note that during boot the best sequence is to mask all IRQs in the interrupt controller/s, then let firmware handle any pending IRQs (e.g. with interrupts enabled, do some "`NOP`" instructions). That way there can't be any pending IRQs when you "`sti`" later (and you can unmask individual IRQ sources when you actually want them unmasked - e.g. when you install a device driver that uses a specific IRQ). Sadly most people (tutorials, GRUB, etc) do everything wrong and just "`cli`" without masking IRQs in the interrupt controller/s (and then do things like remap the PIC chips, etc; which makes things even more confusing), and then end up having to cope with the consequences of doing everything wrong. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to your explanations, I have first initialized all IDT entries with temporary handler and then set "sti" instruction. It worked magically. This eliminates, I think, the exceptions occuring just at the beginning and instead of computer giving another exception when first exception occurs, only "nop" instruction is executed, which is my temporary handler.